# Find local minima and maxima simultanously with scipy.signal.argrelextrema

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to find the local minima and maxima simultanously in an array. I attempted to use Scipy's argrelextrema, but I don't find any documentation on the required comparator function. I attempted to write my own with no success. How could I do this?

I'd like to do this, but only calling `argrelextrema` once instead of iterating over the data twice with `argrelmin` and `argrelmax`, as my data is pretty long, and I have to do this multiple times with it:

```
   import numpy as np
   import scipy.signal as sg

   data = [[xes], [ys]]   #a long 2d array
   max_places = np.array(sg.argrelmax(data[1]))[0] 
   min_places = np.array(sg.argrelmin(data[1]))[0]
   extrema_places = np.contantenate((max_places, min_places))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your goal doesn't make sense.

Using the example in the docs:

```
In [199]: from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
In [200]:  x = np.array([2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0])
In [201]: argrelextrema(x, np.greater)
Out[201]: (array([3, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

this gets the local maxima.  Change to `less` to get the local minima.

```
In [202]: argrelextrema(x, np.less)
Out[202]: (array([1, 5], dtype=int32),)
```

A `lambda` function can work instead of `np.greater`:

```
In [204]: argrelextrema(x, lambda a,b: a>b)
Out[204]: (array([3, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

We could combine > and < with a or, but that just fetches all points (except the ends).

```
In [205]: argrelextrema(x, lambda a,b: (a>b) | (a<b))
Out[205]: (array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

Change a value of `x` so two adjacent values are the same (and thus the lambda test is false)

```
In [211]: x
Out[211]: array([2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0])
In [212]: argrelextrema(x, lambda a,b: (a>b) | (a<b))
Out[212]: (array([1, 2, 3, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

But lets say you could give it desired function, what kind of result would you want?  The maxima and minima strung together as one array, or as two, or as a 2d array?

```
np.array([1,3,5,6])
(np.array([3,6]), np.array([1,5]))
```

Just realized that the result is already a tuple, like `where`, one array per dimension.  In fact that's what it returns:

```
results = _boolrelextrema(data, comparator,
                          axis, order, mode)
return np.where(results)
```

The meat of the task is in that `_boolrelextrama` function; which presumably returns an array like `data`, but with True/False based on the `comparator`.

Are you looking for a turning point, in either direction?  You might want to play with `order`.

```
In [217]: argrelextrema(x, lambda a,b: (a>b) | (a<b), order=2)
Out[217]: (array([1, 3, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

With that modified `x` this order 2 version does return both extrema.  But I doubt if it works if the runs between turns are longer.

See full code in `sg._peak_finding.py` (see also the `[source]` link in the documentation).  `_boolrelextrema` uses the `comparator` to test `data` against several shifted versions of `data`.  `mode` is used by `np.take`.

---

### So in detail

`argrelmax` is  doing:

```
In [262]: x = np.array([2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0])   # data
In [263]: locs = np.arange(0,len(x))          # all indices
In [264]: plus=np.take(x,locs+1,mode='clip')   # shift up, with 'clip'
In [265]: minus=np.take(x,locs-1,mode='clip')  # shift down
In [266]: plus
Out[266]: array([1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0])
In [267]: minus
Out[267]: array([2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1])
In [268]: (x>plus) & (x>minus)             # compare x with shifted arrays
Out[268]: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [269]: np.where(_)
Out[269]: (array([3, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

`argrelmin` generates the same `plus` and `minus`, but then does:

```
In [270]: np.where((x<plus) & (x<minus))
Out[270]: (array([1, 5], dtype=int32),)
```

Doing the 'or' step before `where` interweaves the indices:

```
In [271]: np.where(((x<plus) & (x<minus)) | (x>plus) & (x>minus))
Out[271]: (array([1, 3, 5, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

A combined `min_max` could save on the 2 `take` operations, but otherwise it has do the same 2 comparator steps.

Note that all these operations are in compiled code; there's no Python level iteration on the data array.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my goal. It's not finding all points that are not equal to any adjacent point, rather than getting the indices of  minimas and maximas in a single array, without iterating over the data twice. I added a better example, the original was perhaps misleading.

Comment: `argrelmax` is just `argrelextrema(data, np.greater, axis, order, mode)`.  I demonstrated that, but without `concatenate` to join the 2 arrays into one.

Comment: CONFUSION ... Please write clearly .. what you want to explain ???

Comment: @shantanupathak, if you need help on a particular problem, ask your own question.  Don't try to add on to an old answer (that others found to be adequate).  There are newer questions involving `argrelextrema`.